# Update packages on very old ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php

I want to add Mysqli support to a machine running:

Server Version: Apache/2.2.4 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.3-1ubuntu6.3

I would rather not update more things then I need to.

I run the following: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

However, as the ubuntu version is old I get the following.

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php5-cli php5-mysql php5-mhash php5-xsl php5-pspell php5-snmp php5-curl
  php5-xmlrpc php5-sqlite php5-gd libapache2-mod-php5 php5-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
Err http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com gutsy-updates/main php5-cli 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-cli 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-mysql 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-mhash 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-xsl 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-pspell 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-snmp 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-curl 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-xmlrpc 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-sqlite 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-gd 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main libapache2-mod-php5 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com gutsy-security/main php5-common 5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4
  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-cli_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mysql_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-mhash_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xsl_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-pspell_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-snmp_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-curl_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-xmlrpc_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-sqlite_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-gd_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/libapache2-mod-php5_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php5/php5-common_5.2.3-1ubuntu6.4_i386.deb  404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

**Questions**

1. Can I add mysqli feature using another method instead of sudo-apt get?
2. Even if successful can this break something on the system?

**Update:**

I have tried to add additional sources using the instructions from:

https://superuser.com/questions/339537/where-can-i-get-therepositories-for-old-ubuntu-versions

I have the following in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 7.10 _Gutsy Gibbon_ - Release i386 (20071016)]/ gutsy main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 7.10 _Gutsy Gibbon_ - Release i386 (20071016)]/ gutsy main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates universe
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
#deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy multiverse
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy multiverse
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-updates multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ gutsy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository. This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is
## offered by Canonical and the respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu
## users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu gutsy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu gutsy partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu gutsy-security multiverse

# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/gutsy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/gutsy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/gutsy-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Comment: Gutsy? That went out of support YEARS ago. The only thing you should be doing is replacing it.

Comment: Dumb question: did you sudo apt-get update? What happened after you changed sources.list ?

Comment: Replace that host. You're in for headache and heartache if you don't. The number of php vulnerabilities alone on that version is shocking. I'd recommend that you pick an LTS release given how often you have been updating your software.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using `apt` is to get the `.deb` file for your new package and `dpkg -i` it. Either way, I'm with @meewoK & suggest starting a new build. When I update server OS, I just build a new computer altogether and do a fresh install then migrate everything to it.

I searched and it seems your best option is `dpkg -i`
https://superuser.com/questions/169672/linux-offline-install-apt-get
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97233/fixing-a-broken-packet-system-apt-get

The second link makes me think a guru on Unix.SE might be able to help. You can flag your own question here and ask to get migrated there...?